# how to send mails to the users who are inactive for 2 weeks

Tags: django

I am building a subscription type **Django** model in which i have to identify the users who are inactive for certain duration, say 2 weeks an send mail, does any one know a way to do it with making a cron job

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. add field `last_seen` with type `date`
2. when user logs to your site or do any operation(write, read, ...) update this field
3. create cron job wich search for users with this field equal or less to `today() - 2weeks` and send email for all those users

Comment: thank you, I was looking for a way to avoid cron job..